# how to convert core file to hyprof file

Tags: java, jmap

Recently one of our jvm got crashed.There is a core file that is generated.I want to have a look at that file and find out the reason behiond the crash.
But I am not able to analze the core.I used jmap to analyze it.
And wrote the command-:

**jmap -dump:format=b,file=heap.hprof core 22234**

But I am keep Getting exception:

*Attaching to core 22234 from executable core, please wait...
Error attaching to core file: Windbg Error: OpenDumpFile failed!*

I have the core file in my windows system.Want to analyze it there.Not getting any idea how to do this .Please help.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try to add the -F option:

**jmap -dump:format=b,file=heap.bin -F 22234**